# (Адаптация сайта)Как расположить блоки div в колонку при ширине 700px?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Уже попробовал разные способы, но никак не получается расположить их ровно в столбик. То блок какой то выпадет, то не перемещаются к левой стороне.

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #32508C;
}
.wrapper{
 width: 78.125%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-right: 1px solid;
 border-left: 1px solid;
}
header .main-panel{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
.logo{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 float: left;
}
.main-panel .logo .textLogo{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin: 0;
}
.navig{
 float: right;
}
.navig ul li{
 margin-right: 30px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
.navig li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #E5BA1B;
}
.all-sect{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #F9FAE7;
}
.container{
 width: 80%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #F4B54E;
 float: left;
}
.sidebar{
 width: 20%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #FAFA7E;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar .cont{
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-radius: 20px;
 color: red;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cont a{
 font-family: cursive;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: bordger-box;
}
.container .cont-1{
 width: 57%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid;
 float: left;
}
.container .cont-2{
 width: 42%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid;
 float: right;
}
.container .cont-3{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;

}
.contain{
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
}
.container p{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1150px){
 .sidebar{
  display: none;
 }
 .container{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
 .wrapper{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
 .navig{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="main-panel">
    <div class="logo">
     <p class="textLogo">Logo</p>
    </div>
    <nav class="navig">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="">Главная</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Новости</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Каталог</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">Магазин</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">О нас</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section class="all-sect">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="cont-1 contain">
     <p>Color codes are ways of representing the colors we see everyday in a format that a computer can interpret and display. Commonly used in websites and other software applications, there are a variety of formats, including Hex color codes, RGB and HSL values, and HTML color names, amongst others.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-2 contain">
     <p>Color codes are ways of representing the colors we see everyday in a format that a computer can interpret and display. Commonly used in websites and other software applications, there are a variety of formats, including Hex color codes, RGB and HSL values, and HTML color names, amongst others.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-3 contain">
     <p>Color codes are ways of representing the colors we see everyday in a format that a computer can interpret and display. Commonly used in websites and other software applications, there are a variety of formats, including Hex color codes, RGB and HSL values, and HTML color names, amongst others.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="cont">
     <a href="">Адаптивность</a>
     <a href="">Навигация</a>
     <a href="">Сотрудничество</a>
     <a href="">Контакты</a>
     <a href="">О нас</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .cont-1, .container .cont-2 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .cont-3 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16k3jp29/